# Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E37

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, foreach-loop-container

I know other people have already posted similar error and got multiple answers/solutions, None of these worked for me. also I AM A NEWBIE, so here is my situation:

So I created a package that has a foreachloop and within it a data task flow. I have a source with 20 excel files. The whole thing runs perfectly fine. I finished the project deployment and set up a job agent on my sql server. and to make sure job agent run right, I truncated my tables on the database. when I manually started the job, it did not populate the tables as supposed to. I went back into SSIS packages and found these error messages:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsbFL.png)

> [Excel Source ProspectFiles [182]] Error: SSIS Error Code
> DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code:
> 0x80040E37.
>
> [Excel Source ProspectFiles [182]] Error: Opening a rowset for
> "Sheet1$" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: "Excel Source ProspectFiles" failed validation
> and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".

well, it appears that instead of the foreachloop running all the excel files, it only runs the 1st file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaBZ6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your Excel connection manager must be using a variable to refer to the name of the file, which the loop is updating. Check that your default value for that variable is still valid.

Also, if you developed the package on your machine and then deployed it to a another server, then the package is no longer looking for the files on your machine, it's looking for it on the server you deployed the package to.